# PID from socket number on Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, winsock, pid

I need to count amount of bytes sent and received from the network by various applications. First I thought about using [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol), but there is a lot of applications that do not use LSP at all ([SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) for example). This is why I have written a small sniffer. This application works on the IP level and collects data using *recvfrom*.

So I have the address of the remote host, local and remote ports. This is pretty cool, but I also need to have the PID of the local socket owner. So, is there a simple way to obtain such PID?

The workaround is using GetTcpTable, GetUdpTable Or AllocateAndGetUdpExTableFromStack  and AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack (there are a lot of differences in those functions between [Windows 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_2000), [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP), [Windows XP SP2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP#Service_Pack_2) and [Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista)) and to lookup result tables, but it seems inelegant and inefficient...

So is there a kind of A "GetPIDOfSocket" function? The resolution should be [Win32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) (no [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)) only, as various languages can be used, e.g. C++ and [Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi).

Comment: As you seem to have joined very recently, allow me to give you a hint: It is usually helpful to provide what programming language you are using. You still have one empty tag slot to fill it in :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting PID of peer socket on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429887/getting-pid-of-peer-socket-on-windows)

Comment: Slightly related: *[How do I find out which process is listening on a TCP or UDP port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `GetTcpTable` or `AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack` is not a workaround. It's actually how other *netstat*-type applications work.

As far as I know, there isn't any Win32 `"GetPIDOfSocket"` function. Your only option is to poll using the port table functions. But at least you can code it up yourself and don't have to spawn the *netstat* process.

See the [Sysinternals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysinternals) C source code for `netstatp` [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20060409151614/http://www.sysinternals.com/Files/NetstatpSource.zip). There's not a lot of it and it's well worth a look.