# How to know which Local Application Connected to my socket (Windows)

Tags: windows-services, sockets, tcp, winsock

I have a windows services that bind to some TCP port, this port is use for IPC between my application.

Is there a programming (WinAPI/WinSocket and etc) way to know which application connected to my port?

i.e. in my Windows Services I would like to get a PID of the process that connected to my port.

Comment: This is similar to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819708/pid-from-socket-number-on-windows The answer is moreless the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for WinAPI way of doing the same as `netstat`. You probably want the following API:
[`GetExtendedTcpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928(VS.85).aspx)

Look for the results with `TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL` argument.

The resulting `MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID` structure has many [`MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366913(VS.85).aspx) structures that has `dwOwningPid` which is the process ID you are looking for.

Comment: This is supported on WinXP SP2+. If you look for older versions compatibility look for AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack API.

Comment: Sorry, but this was not my questions, I wanted to know the PID of the application that connected to my port, not the PID of the application that bind to the port.

Comment: You can't know that from remote machine. You only know the source port and IP.

Comment: Your question is not so clear. In case you are looking for the PID of a LOCAL application that is connected to some local service, you can use GetExtendedTcpTable or AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack to see both sides: the listening one and the connecting one.

Comment: If that was helpful do you mind raising the rating of this answer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what process is using (listening on or connected using) your ports, use the following command:

`netstat -a -b -o -n`

`-a` will show you all connection (even if they in LISTENING state)

`-b` will show you the application executable that uses that port

`-o` will show you the PID of the application

`-n` will not do dns translations (you probably don't need these for knowing about the application), not necessary

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i need the programming way to do this.