# Getting PID of peer socket on Windows

Tags: winapi, web, proxy, winsock, pid

I am writing a web proxy and when a request comes in (typically from the browser on the machine), I'd like to also get the pid and any other requesting application.
Is there any way to determine this using Win32?

Comment: Fiddler provides the details of the process that initiated the request. Therefore there should be some way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is only possible if the client and server are running on the same machine.

When a client is connected to the proxy, the proxy can use [`getpeername()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738533.aspx) to query the socket for the remote client IP/Port (or use the IP/Port reported by `accept()`) and [`getsockname()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738543.aspx) to get its local server IP/Port.  Then the proxy can use [`GetTcpTable2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406.aspx) (IPv4) or [`GetTcp6Table2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408405.aspx) (IPv6) to retrieve a list of active TCP connections and loop through it looking for a connection that matches the IP/Port pairs.  If found, the list entry will tell you the process ID that owns that connection.

For example:

```
DWORD GetClientPid(SOCKET client)
{
    DWORD pid = 0;

    sockaddr_in ServerAddr = {0};
    int ServerAddrSize = sizeof(ServerAddr);

    sockaddr_in ClientAddr = {0};
    int ClientAddrSize = sizeof(ClientAddr);

    if ((getsockname(client, (sockaddr*)&ServerAddr, &ServerAddrSize) == 0) &&
        (getpeername(client, (sockaddr*)&ClientAddr, &ClientAddrSize) == 0))
    {
        PMIB_TCPTABLE2 TcpTable = NULL;
        ULONG TcpTableSize = 0;
        ULONG result;

        do
        {
            result = GetTcpTable2(TcpTable, &TcpTableSize, TRUE);
            if (result != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
                break;

            LocalFree(TcpTable);
            TcpTable = (PMIB_TCPTABLE2) LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, TcpTableSize);
        }
        while (TcpTable != NULL);

        if (result == NO_ERROR)
        {
            for (DWORD dw = 0; dw < TcpTable->dwNumEntries; ++dw)
            {
                PMIB_TCPROW2 row = &(TcpTable->table[dw]);

                if ((row->dwState == MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB) &&
                    (row->dwLocalAddr == ClientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr) &&
                    ((row->dwLocalPort & 0xFFFF) == ClientAddr.sin_port) &&
                    (row->dwRemoteAddr == ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr) &&
                    ((row->dwRemotePort & 0xFFFF) == ServerAddr.sin_port))
                {
                    pid = row->dwOwningPid;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        LocalFree(TcpTable);
    }

    return pid;
}
```

```
SOCKET client = accept(server, NULL, NULL);
if (client != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    DWORD ClientPid = GetClientPid(client);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was helpful. I'm interested also, why are there 16 bits masked in `row->dwLocalPort & 0xFFFF` out of the 32 DWORD bits in dwLocalPort ? Is it because ports can only go from 0 to 65536-1 and we do not need those bits and it somehow gives us better performance? Not sure if anything is changed by that bitmask. Thanks.

Comment: Per the [`MIB_TCPROW2` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb485761.aspx): "*The maximum size of an IP port number is 16 bits, so only the lower 16 bits should be used. **The upper 16 bits may contain uninitialized data**.*" The mask is used to forcibly zero out the upper bits so any uninitialized data does not affect the comparisons.