# Restricting access to a TCP service to the current user session

Tags: sockets, security, winapi, winsock

I have developed a TCP service which actually acts as a HTTP server, accepting connections from localhost only. Some JavaScript web-based applications, executed within a browser on this client machine, can then make requests to this service using AJAX, to perform some advanced stuff that is usually forbidden from a JavaScript app (like accessing some hardware resources). Fine.

The problem is that, if multiple users are logged on the same machine (using fast user switching, or if this system is used on a windows server, ...), there should be multiple instances of the TCP service running. I can bind it to a dynamic TCP port within a given range and make a bit of polling from JavaScript to find on which port it is bound to. But I can't quite figure out how to guarantee that the client will end up connecting to the TCP service instance that corresponds to the same user session.

How can I make sure, from my local service, that only peers that belong to the same user session are able to connect? (knowing it is gauranteed that the client app and my service are running on the same machine)

I have a few ideas, but nothing really obvious: try to guess the [peer PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429887/getting-pid-of-peer-socket-on-windows), and check on which session the client process is running on (using ProcessIdToSessionId). But it seems a bit complicated. Or maybe making some WSASetSocketSecurity sauce to ensure that only processes from the same session (or user) are able to connect (how should I fill in the SOCKET_SECURITY_SETTINGS structure, then?).

Any ideas are welcome. The main target is windows, but I'll be even happier if the answer addresses other platforms (linux, mac OS).

Comment: Have you ever found an acceptable solution to this situation?

Comment: @MathieuFortin Unfortunately not. I didn't really try to implement the given suggestions: this was too convoluted, so I simply changed a few things in the logic to guarantee that if a client connects to the wrong server, nothing really wrong happens. The peer PID solution might work, though. And if you have other realistic ideas, don't hesitate to answer.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can't limit sockets to specific sessions. And certainly not in any portable way. Sockets simply don't have that fine level of control over their bindings.

The simplest thing you can really do is bind each listening server to a different IP/port pair that is unique to each session.

Otherwise, at least on Windows, it is possible to enumerate active TCP connections (`GetTcpTable2()` and friends). Once you have `accept()`'ed a client connection, get the IP/port pairs of that socket (`getsockname()` and `getpeername()`), find the corresponding entry in the system table containing those pairs to find the owning process ID, query the session ID of that process (`ProcessIdToSessionId()`), and then disconnect the client socket if it belongs to a session that is different than the server process that accepted it.

Comment: I'm ok with having a server for each session, each listening to a different port. This is already the case. The problem is then, from the JavaScript, guess on which port the server belonging to the same session is bound. Since I can't do much from JavaScript running in a browser (getting any info related to the OS session is impossible), I thought the way to solve my problem would more likely be from the server side. But if there is a way to solve the whole problem from the client side, I'm OK.

Comment: @dim sockets are not session-bound. The only way for Javascript to discover a random port is to try every possible port until successful. Otherwise, the server needs to publish its port where Javascript can access it. I would suggest a different approach. Don't use session-specific servers at all. Use one server that runs globally, and have every session connect to the same server, then use client information to identify sessions and restrict access to data that is not in a client's session.