# Why is a bitmask of 0xFFFF used when dwLocalPort from PMIB_TCPROW2 structure?

Tags: c++, bitmask, dword

I found this answer to be useful: [Getting PID of peer socket on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429887/getting-pid-of-peer-socket-on-windows)
.. but also intriguing.

**I'm wondering**: why are there 16 bits masked in `row->dwLocalPort & 0xFFFF` out of the 32 DWORD bits in dwLocalPort?

I know that bitmasks are used to add more information into 1 number, but it seems for me that here it is not necessary. Am I overlooking something simple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per MSDN "The maximum size of an IP port number is 16 bits, so only the lower 16 bits should be used. The upper 16 bits may contain uninitialized data."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/subscriptions/bb485761.aspx

Comment: So I wonder why they left those bits uninitialized rather than setting them to zero?

Comment: @MarkRansom • we can blame my coworker Raymond Chen.  He gets a lot of blame for other developer's messes.  (I kid!  I kid!  Raymond is awesome.  He's one of the staunch stalwarts that keeps Windows to be backwards compatible as much as humanly possible.)

Comment: I know you kid, Raymond Chen is one of my heroes. He even posts on StackOverflow now and again, I don't know how he finds the time.

Comment: Did not see that explanation before, thanks a lot. However, I though that clearing bits is not and'ing them, but negating and then anding (x & ~x) ?

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius • the `~x` is the bitwise complement operator.  An `(x & ~x)` is 0 ... so there was probably something similar-but-different going on.  The `& 0xFFFF is a mask to only allow the lower 16-bits.

Comment: Sorry, I understood it now ... FFFF is 16 lower bits set to 1 and 16 upper bits set to 0. Since we want to 0 out the upper 16 bits in the DWORD, we need to set the lower bits to 1 in the mask and the upper bits to 0, since AND with all 1's always preserves the original bits in the masked value.