# How to add some WinAPI functions to Squid's source code and build it via Cygwin in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, cygwin, squid

I would like to get process id peer socket like here [Getting PID of peer socket on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429887/getting-pid-of-peer-socket-on-windows) in Squid but any attempt to include the <iphlpapi.h> header in source code of the Squid results in a build error with a lot of conflicts of the declaration...

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Add the errors you get to the question.

Comment: @nevilad thanks for the answer. I solved it by dynamically loading iphlpapi.dll using the `dlopen` and getting a pointer to `GetTcpTable2` using the `dlsym`.